# Embedding auto-generated UML diagrams to LaTeX output

Tags: doxygen

Is it possible to embed the UML diagrams generated with `UML_LOOK = YES` in the LaTeX output?

Edit:

I am using Doxygen 1.9.1. The output of `doxygen -x Doxyfile` looks like this:

```
# Difference with default Doxyfile 1.9.1
PROJECT_NAME           = ...
JAVADOC_AUTOBRIEF      = YES
TOC_INCLUDE_HEADINGS   = 0
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = YES
INPUT                  = ...
FILE_PATTERNS          = *.cpp \
                         *.h
RECURSIVE              = YES
EXAMPLE_PATH           = .../examples
USE_MDFILE_AS_MAINPAGE = README.md
HTML_FORMULA_FORMAT    = svg
MATHJAX_RELPATH        = https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.2/
LATEX_CMD_NAME         = pdflatex
HAVE_DOT               = YES
COLLABORATION_GRAPH    = NO
UML_LOOK               = YES
TEMPLATE_RELATIONS     = YES
DOT_IMAGE_FORMAT       = svg
INTERACTIVE_SVG        = YES
DOT_TRANSPARENT        = YES
```

For a minimal source file like

```
class Lol {
    void foo(){}
};

class Bar : public Lol {
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    
    return 0;
}
```

The HTML output contains this kind of diagram:

[image]

but the LaTeX PDF contains no graphs.

## Edit 2

There seems to be a problem with `dot`?

```
Executing external command `dot ".../html/classBar__inherit__graph.dot" -Tsvg -o ".../html/classBar__inherit__graph.svg"`
Executing external command `dot ".../latex/classLol__inherit__graph.dot" -Tpdf -o ".../latex/classLol__inherit__graph.pdf"`
Executing external command `dot ".../html/classLol__inherit__graph.dot" -Tsvg -o ".../html/classLol__inherit__graph.svg"`
Executing external command `dot ".../html/graph_legend.dot" -Tsvg -o ".../html/graph_legend.svg"`
Executing external commanerror: Failed to extract bounding box from generated diagram file .../latex/classLol__inherit__graph.pdf
error: Problems running dot: exit code=0, command='dot', arguments='".../latex/classLol__inherit__graph.dot" -Tpdf -o ".../latex/classLol__inherit__graph.pdf"'
error: Failed to extract bounding box from generated diagram file .../latex/classBar__inherit__graph.pdf
error: Problems running dot: exit code=0, command='dot', arguments='".../latex/classBar__inherit__graph.dot" -Tpdf -o ".../latex/classBar__inherit__graph.pdf"'
error: Failed to extract bounding box from generated diagram file .../latex/classBar__inherit__graph.pdf
error: problem writing FIG 0 figure!
```

Comment: Which version of doxygen? What did you try so far, i.e. give a small code example + the used doxygen settings (that are different of the default settings, i.e. result of `doxygen -x Doxyfile`).

Comment: Thank you for your patience! Some context would have helped. I will try to produce some minimal example.

Answer (score 0):

A comment does not accept images, but when I run your example with doxygen 1.9.1 I do see the UML diagram in the LaTeX output:

[image]

and

[image]

I ran the given example with the extra option `-d extcmd` (so `doxygen -d extmd`) which also showed me that the uml diagram was created.

```
Executing external command `dot ".../html/graph_legend.dot" -Tsvg -o ".../html/graph_legend.svg"`
Executing external command `dot ".../html/class_bar__inherit__graph.dot" -Tsvg -o ".../html/class_bar__inherit__graph.svg"`
Executing external command `dot ".../html/class_lol__inherit__graph.dot" -Tsvg -o ".../html/class_lol__inherit__graph.svg"`
Executing external command `dot ".../latex/class_bar__inherit__graph.dot" -Tpdf -o ".../latex/class_bar__inherit__graph.pdf"`
Executing external command `dot ".../html/inherit_graph_0.dot" -Tsvg -o ".../html/inherit_graph_0.svg"`
Executing external command `dot ".../latex/class_lol__inherit__graph.dot" -Tpdf -o ".../latex/class_lol__inherit__graph.pdf"`
Executing external command `dot ".../html/class_lol__inherit__graph.dot" -Tcmapx -o ".../html/class_lol__inherit__graph.map"`
Executing external command `dot ".../html/class_bar__inherit__graph.dot" -Tcmapx -o ".../html/class_bar__inherit__graph.map"`
Executing external command `dot ".../html/inherit_graph_0.dot" -Tcmapx -o ".../html/inherit_graph_0.map"`
```

So as far as I can see the UML diagrams are created.

Note: the current doxygen version is 1.9.5

Comment: OK, that's surprising. I'll dig into it.

Comment: Uhm, it seems that my `dot` is broken. I added a log above.

Comment: Which version of dot are you using?

Comment: Just crossed my mind maybe it has to do with https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/9320/commits(which is in 1.9.5) it might also be that your dot version uses a Cairo version that compresses some information (see https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/9319), but this can only be seen by inspecting the pdf file of the image.

Comment: This seems to be case! My PDF look like the "bad" PDF in the link. I will keep an eye on that bug. Thanks a lot, since it was failing silently and the PDF looked fine otherwise, I thought it was a missing feature.

Comment: Well it is not a bad pdf but doxygen doesn't yet know how to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, but Cairo 1.17.6 changes the way that the PDFs are encoded, and doxygen fails to process the PDFs generated by `dot`.

See https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/9319, and albert's comment below (who figured this out, I am just summarizing the answer).